How to get all form controls inside a custom validator (field groups dynamically created)
I am building a dynamic form, using form builder as below:
runnable code I have been trying so far in stackblitz
I have read docs and seen this e.g. but couldn't find an example where the other dynamically added form control values are fetched and do some action with them ..
Here I wanted to check the sum of current entered count field and the rest of the count fields is less than the availableCount ... If it is greater I wanted to show / return an error and make the current control invalid
I understood the part of returning an object from customValidator, but the way I am trying in my above code is giving me errros on getting the feildsArray from form, not sure what I am missing though ..
I took AI help too but couldn't get it correct ... any help is appreciated, thanks

When you use a formArray and want to control, you should create the validator over the formArray or check all the elements of the array each time you change
NOTE: I don't like use the "ugly bind", so simply access to the formArray from control using, in this case control?.parent?.parent as FormArray
Well, if "availableCount" can change after we create the formGroup, we need use bind, else we can do
countFieldValidator(limit:number){
    return (control: FormControl)=>{
    const fieldsArray = control?.parent?.parent as FormArray;
    if (fieldsArray) {
      const totalCount = fieldsArray?.controls
        .map((fieldGroup) => fieldGroup.get('count')?.value)
        .reduce((sum, count) => sum + (count || 0), 0);

      if (totalCount > limit) {
        return { countExceeded: true };
      }
      //if there're no errors we checked all the other with error
      //if we use bind or not we need check
      fieldsArray.controls.forEach(x=>{
        const other=x.get('count')
        if (other!=control && other.invalid)
          other.updateValueAndValidity()
      })

    }
    return null;
  }
}

And write
count: [
    null,
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.min(1),
      this.countFieldValidator(this.availableCount),
    ],


Hey @Eliseo, thank you ... sorry I didn't get the last part of updateValueAndValidity, why do we need to check the condition and call it ?

@KcH, imagine you have tree "counts". You give the values: 90,40 and 20. (the second one give you error) You change the first one to 10. Angular only "validate" the FomControl when you change the input ( * ). So, the second are showed as invalid because you have not validate it. In your problem, when one is valid, all the rest are valid too, so if valid you loop over the rest of formsControls and if one is invalid, you force the "check". ( * ) the typical e.g. is a form with password and repeat password (when you change the password you should validate the repeat password too).

Thank you so much @Eliseo ... makes sense, but the input gets validated not as we type but when on blur ... not exactly sure why since we haven't defined that as onBlur too

If you look at the code, you have declared myForm: FormGroup but you have not initialized it with a value, so the initial value will be undefined, So the validator function was trying to access a property of undefined and was throwing error, we can just use ?. which is typescript safe check which will perform auto null check and prevent these sorts of errors.
snippet
  countFieldValidator(control: FormControl) {
    const fieldsArray = this.myForm?.get('fieldsArray') as FormArray; // <- changed here!
    const totalCount = fieldsArray?.controls // <- changed here!
      .map((fieldGroup) => fieldGroup.get('count')?.value) // <- changed here!
      .reduce((sum, count) => sum + (count || 0), 0);

    if (totalCount > this.availableCount) {
      return { countExceeded: true };
    }
    return null;
  }

safe check example in playground
ts
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  FormControl,
  FormArray,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class FormsComponent {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  availableCount = 100; // Set the available count limit here

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      fieldsArray: this.fb.array([this.createFieldGroup()]),
    });
  }

  createFieldGroup(): FormGroup {
    const newFieldGroup = this.fb.group({
      count: [
        null,
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.min(1),
          this.countFieldValidator.bind(this),
        ],
      ],
      group: [null, Validators.required],
    });
    return newFieldGroup;
  }

  get fieldsArray() {
    return this.myForm.get('fieldsArray') as FormArray;
  }

  countFieldValidator(control: FormControl) {
    const fieldsArray = this.myForm?.get('fieldsArray') as FormArray;
    const totalCount = fieldsArray?.controls
      .map((fieldGroup) => fieldGroup.get('count')?.value)
      .reduce((sum, count) => sum + (count || 0), 0);

    if (totalCount > this.availableCount) {
      return { countExceeded: true };
    }
    return null;
  }

  addFields(): void {
    this.fieldsArray.push(this.createFieldGroup());
  }

  removeFields(index: number) {
    this.fieldsArray.removeAt(index);
  }
}

html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="form-container">
  <div formArrayName="fieldsArray" class="form-group-container">
    <div
      *ngFor="let fieldGroup of fieldsArray.controls; let i = index"
      [formGroupName]="i"
      class="form-group"
    >
      <mat-form-field class="count-field">
        <mat-label>Count</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="count" type="number" matInput />
        <mat-error *ngIf="fieldGroup?.controls?.count?.errors?.required">
          Field is mandatory
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error
          *ngIf="
            !fieldGroup?.controls?.count?.errors?.required &&
            fieldGroup?.controls?.count?.errors?.countExceeded
          "
        >
          Sum of inputs exceeds 100, kindly reduce the value(s)
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <button class="remove-button" (click)="removeFields(i)">delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" label="Add" (click)="addFields()">Add</button>
</form>

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks a lot, is it because I'm creating one field group in the constructor itself and the validate method doesn't have access to form which is not yet initialized ? I am trying to understand why we couldn't access all controls in form or maybe is it just there is no control for the first time  ..

@KcH Maybe angular compiler found the error  and reported it, since typescript/javascript has strict checks that might check for undefined, its confusing to me too actually! :( But gist is we need to initialize a value even a dummy one like myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({}); this will get rid of the error!

yeah its not clear or atleast there should be an example in the docs saying to initialize with a dummy group (maybe it is there already) , thanks for all your help :)

@NarenMurali, we need check the others controls when no errors

For the future reference !!
Few comments and improvements suggested by JB Nizbet (Angular Ninja) from the discord community where I asked the same Q
JB:

The problem is that you're setting a validator on a FormGroup and this
validator, instead of validating what it should validate, i.e. the
AbstractControl that it receives as argumenbt, tries to access some
other part of the whole form. Don't do that.
Put the validator on the control / group / array that has all the
information you need to do the validation, and get the information it
needs using the argument it receives.

Me:
so something as this ?
this.fb.group({
        count: [..],  // not here 
        group: [...]
     },
     {
        validators: []   // but here ?
     }
)

JB:

No, that still wouldn't be right. The validator needs all the values
of the form array to do its job, so that's where it should be set:
Working sample
Stackblitz

All thanks to JB Nizet for their suggestions 

See that, althought is correct, each change in any control of the formArray -this include any change of any group- makes the validation. This is ok when the formArray is a formArray of formGroup of two or three elements (or when the formArray is a formArray of FormControls), but it's not aceptable when, e.g. the elements of the formArray is a formGroup of four o more formControls

Futhermore, if you're using material, the error it's not show in the correct place, feel free to comment to JB Nizet

Thanks @Eliseo, yes I informed on the same he suggested to make few changes: to store the control of that specific count that makes the sum exceed in the error detected by the validator and then test if the current count is that one in the view but I didn't get it fully
